# Best way to remove remove values from variable? create an array, or using regex? or with Xpath?

Tags: python, regex, arrays, xpath

Im trying to extract some fields from the output at the end of this question with the following code:

```
doc = LH.fromstring(html2)
tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath("//td[not(*)]"))

for a,b,c in zip(*[tds]*3):
    print (a,b,c)
```

What i expect is to extract only the fields notificationNodeName,notificationNodeName,packageName,notificationEnabled

The main problem with that is because i want to put the result into a database. and i need to, instead receiveing:

Actual code returns:

```
('JDBCAdapter', 'JDBCAdapter', 'Package:Notif')
('Package', 'yes', 'Package_2:Notif')
('Package_2', 'yes')
```

What i need:

```
('Package:Notif','Package', 'yes')
('Package_2:Notif','Package_2', 'yes')
```

An unly solution that i found was:

```
doc = LH.fromstring(html2)
tds = (td.text_content() for td in doc.xpath("//td"))

for td, val in zip(*[tds]*2):
    if td == 'notificationNodeName':
        notificationNodeName = val
    elif td == 'packageName':
        packageName = val
    elif td == 'notificationEnabled':
        notificationEnabled = val
        print (notificationNodeName,packageName,notificationEnabled)
```

It works but doenst seen right for me, im sure it can be a better way to do it.

Original HTML Output:

```
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top"><b>adapterTypeName</b></td>
<td>JDBCAdapter</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>adapterTypeNameList</b></td>
<td>
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td>JDBCAdapter</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>notificationDataList</b></td>
<td>
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<td><table bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top"><b>notificationNodeName</b></td>
<td>package:Notif</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>packageName</b></td>
<td>Package</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>notificationEnabled</b></td>
<td>unsched</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table bgcolor="#dddddd" border="1">
<tbody><tr>
<td valign="top"><b>notificationNodeName</b></td>
<td>Package_2:notif</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>packageName</b></td>
<td>package_2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><b>notificationEnabled</b></td>
<td>yes</td>
</tr>

and continues to more ... non relevant repetitive data.
```

Comment: I've rarely seen a problem that is more easily solved with xpath than with BeautifulSoup. (Actually, I've never been able to figure what class of problems xpath was supposed to be good for).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the excellent lxml and it's cssselect functionality for basically most HTML parsing.

You can then select each field you are interested in thusly:

```
from lxml import html
root = html.parse(open('your/file.html')).getroot()

sibling_content = lambda x: [b.getparent().getnext().text_content() for b in
                             root.cssselect("td b:contains('{0}')".format(x))]

fields = ['notificationNodeName', 'packageName', 'notificationEnabled']

for item in zip(*[sibling_content(field) for field in fields]):
    print item
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how i can add the html2 var into root = html.parse(open('your/file.html')).getroot() ? when i run it i get the normal error of file not found. – Thales Pereira 13 mins ago

Comment: Assuming this variable is a string, there is an alternative API which would be: 
root = html.fromstring(html2)
Full API docs for lxml: http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html

Comment: Thanks you, and sorry for the lazyness, i found it after a few minutes after replying, searching on the API documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

I would also recommend lxml - it's the de facto standard for parsing XML or HTML with Python.

As an alternative to David's approach, here's a solution using xpaths:

```
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree


html_file = open('test.html', 'r')
root = html.parse(html_file).getroot()

# Strip those annoying <b> tags for easier xpaths
etree.strip_tags(root,'b')

data_list = root.xpath("//td[text()='notificationDataList']/following-sibling::*")[0]

node_names = data_list.xpath("//td[text()='notificationNodeName']/following-sibling::*/text()")
package_names = data_list.xpath("//td[text()='packageName']/following-sibling::*/text()")
enableds = data_list.xpath("//td[text()='notificationEnabled']/following-sibling::*/text()")

print zip(node_names, package_names, enableds)
```

Output:

```
[('package:Notif', 'Package', 'unsched'),
 ('Package_2:notif', 'package_2', 'yes')]
```